# db expression for rails activerecord fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

How can I fill some database field with value, returned by mysql function?

In Yii(PHP) I wrote something like

$post->my_time=new CDbExpression('NOW()')

How can I do that with Rails 3 ActiveRecord?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result of a MySQL function with [select_value](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_value)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('SELECT NOW()')
```

Or you can run `update()` to store the value directly.

But it's generally not recommended to use complex database logic with ActiveRecord.

Comment: It requires one extra query to database. But... I will use this solution if no more elegant. Thanks

Comment: Now in my opinion all logic must be placed into rails code. It's bad idea to use foreign keys, NOT NULL fields, views, triggers and so on in DB. Database must be "dumb" - only tables with indices. In this case the best way is to use ruby functions to get current time.

Comment: I can only add while having logic like procedures database-side is wrong, having constraints database-side, like foreign keys, is crucial to database integrity.